# Convert string to function in v8

Tags: c++, v8

I'm trying to hardcode a function as string, turn it into a function and run it.

```
Local<Function> cb = "function(){ console.log('HELLO BOSS'); }";
int argc=0;
v8::Handle<v8::Value> * argv;
cb->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(),argc,argv);
```

Compiler sais I can't do it directly:

```
      error C2664: 'v8::Handle<T>::Handle(T *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'v8::Function *'
      with
      [
         T=v8::Function
      ]
      Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast 
      x.cpp(15) : see reference to function template instantiation 'v8::Local<T>::Local<const char>(S *)' being compiled
      with
      [
         T=v8::Function,
         S=const char
      ]
```

How can I do it then? Also, where are all the goodies (eval, new Function, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it. Boy I love this stuff.

```
v8::Script::Compile(v8::String::New(
    " console.log('WORKS BOSS'); "
    " console.log('Happy?'); "
    " console.log('2+2=' + (2+2)); "
))->Run();
```

I don't know if it's right (right as in "any risk associated") but it seems to work.

Comment: You are encouraged to accept your own answer if it works best for you.